# The multi-part identifier could not be bound. Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not able to query it is showing me error messages.

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17 The multi-part identifier
>   "D1.DesignationId" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 18 The multi-part identifier "A.EmployeeId" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18 The multi-part identifier
>   "D1.EmpId" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
>   The multi-part identifier "A.EmployeeId" could not be bound.

My query code is:

```
SELECT     
    RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.ReqSampleDetailsId, 
    RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.ReqId, 
    D1.EmpName, 
    D1.DesignationId, 
    G.Name, 
    RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.PreparedBy
FROM 
    RequisitionAuthoritySignatury 
    INNER JOIN AuthoritySignatury A ON RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.PreparedBy = A.AuthoritySignaturyId 
    INNER JOIN AuthoritySignatury B ON RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.PreparedBy = B.AuthoritySignaturyId 
    INNER JOIN AuthoritySignatury C ON RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.PreparedBy = C.AuthoritySignaturyId 
    INNER JOIN EmployeeMaster D1
    INNER JOIN EmployeeMaster E
    INNER JOIN EmployeeMaster F
    INNER JOIN DesignationMaster G 
        ON D1.DesignationId = G.DesignationId 
        ON A.EmployeeId = D1.EmpId
    INNER JOIN DesignationMaster H 
        ON E.DesignationId = H.DesignationId 
        ON A.EmployeeId = E.EmpId
    INNER JOIN DesignationMaster I 
        ON F.DesignationId = I.DesignationId 
        ON A.EmployeeId = F.EmpId
WHERE 
    RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.ReqId=158 AND 
    RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.ReqSampleDetailsId=260;
```

Comment: D1.DesignationId,D1.EmpId colud not means those columns are not available in that table EmployeeMaster

Comment: I am not getting your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joins are "completed" in the order in which their respective `ON` clauses appear. Each `ON` clause "completes" the nearest `JOIN` which hasn't yet been completed. Because you're scrambling your `ON` clauses around, at the point at which you reference `D1`, the join that brings `D1` into scope hasn't been completed and so you get the error. Move your `ON`s to the `JOIN`s that they're trying to constrain:

```
SELECT     
    RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.ReqSampleDetailsId, 
    RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.ReqId, 
    D1.EmpName, 
    D1.DesignationId, 
    G.Name, 
    RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.PreparedBy
FROM 
    RequisitionAuthoritySignatury 
    INNER JOIN AuthoritySignatury A ON RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.PreparedBy = A.AuthoritySignaturyId 
    INNER JOIN AuthoritySignatury B ON RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.PreparedBy = B.AuthoritySignaturyId 
    INNER JOIN AuthoritySignatury C ON RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.PreparedBy = C.AuthoritySignaturyId 
    INNER JOIN EmployeeMaster D1
        ON A.EmployeeId = D1.EmpId
    INNER JOIN EmployeeMaster E
        ON A.EmployeeId = E.EmpId
    INNER JOIN EmployeeMaster F
        ON A.EmployeeId = F.EmpId
    INNER JOIN DesignationMaster G 
        ON D1.DesignationId = G.DesignationId 
    INNER JOIN DesignationMaster H 
        ON E.DesignationId = H.DesignationId 
    INNER JOIN DesignationMaster I 
        ON F.DesignationId = I.DesignationId 
WHERE 
    RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.ReqId=158 AND 
    RequisitionAuthoritySignatury.ReqSampleDetailsId=260;
```

Comment: Thank you @Damien_The_Unbeliever it is working for me as aspected.